# JpaRepository- DB operation working without @Transactional

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using JPA repository. Below is the configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/> 
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.ca.dao"></jpa:repositories>

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="location">
            <beans:value>classpath:database.properties</beans:value>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.ca.bean"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"></beans:bean>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="jpaProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="com.ca.common.CustomDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

POM Entry:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Below is the JPA class:

```
package com.ca.dao.client;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.ca.bean.client.ClientBean;

@Repository
public interface ClientDAO  extends JpaRepository<ClientBean, Serializable>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ClientBean>{

}
```

Below is the service class where I'm trying to save bean into DB

```
package com.ca.service.impl;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.ca.dao.client.ClientDAO;

@Service
public class ScheduleTaskServiceImpl implements ScheduleTaskService {

    @Autowired
    private ClientDAO clientDAO;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void create(ClientBean cb) {
        clientDAO.save(db);
        throw new RuntimeException("sdfdsf");
    }
}
```

In above service class, I'm throwing runtime exception after saving the details.Problem is even after throwing runtime exception, transaction is not getting rollback. Entry is still getting created in DB.
I 'm seeing the same behaviour even after removing @Transactional. That means even if I'll remove @Transactional, it will save entry in DB.

What's wrong here? Please help.

Data is getting inserted into DB even if i remove @Transactional

Comment: Is your database in auto-commit mode?

Comment: How to verify that? I'm using MySQL 5.5.50

Comment: I tried SET autocommit=0; also. It didnt worked